# Improper styling- Alignment issue for input element & button in simple html form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a new contact form into my already running website.

I downloaded an HTML snippet & added it to my page. Here the [downloaded code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pqto85fd9jq27s6/AADvsFJ2xhgH8aygmFaFaDkpa?dl=0).

The code is built using bootstrap framework. It looks good. But when I implemented it into my website, some things didn't fit in places. The upload element is outlined. It doesn't remain in style. And the button has overflowed the div.

I want to align them properly. Any help??

Style:

```
.contact-info h4 {
    color: #8F99A4;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.contact-info h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.contact-us {
    padding: 3em 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact">
                    <div class="contact-info">
                        <h4>Contact Us</h4>
                        <h3>FOR MORE INFORMATION</h3>
                        <div class="hril">
                            <div class="rounded-1">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/rounded-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""/></a>
                            </div>
                            <form action=""  id="contactus" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input name="frmname" style="width: 80%" type="text" class="text" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
                            <input name="phonenumber" style="width: 40%" type="number" class="text" required="required" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
                            <input name="frmemail" type="email" style="width: 40%"  class="text" placeholder="Email Id" required/>
                            <textarea name="comments" style="width: 80%" required="required" placeholder="Comments & Questions"></textarea>
                            <div>
                                <input placeholder="resume" type="file" style="width: 80%">
                            </div>
                            <input name="submit_button" type="submit" value="SEND" />
                            </br>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: .hril in style.css line : 356 has fixed height. Can you remove this and add some more padding.

Comment: That was successful. But what about the input element 'browse' ?? @murnax

Comment: because your container (form) doesn't have padding and by default bootstrap assign input[type="file"] display property as 'block'. so your input file look like this.

try to add this style to your input file class
.file-upload{
width: 93%;
display: inline-block;
}

Comment: there is no input file in your dropbox file. you can add it like this

<input type="file" class="file-upload">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a few changes in the css section.

```
.hril{
    background-color:#F9F9F9;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 5em;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 5em;

}
```

Changed the height to 400px; That solved the button issue.

Added a new style for input file element.

```
input[type=file]
{
    width: 46%;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #A0A8B2;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Well...That was it. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the advice from the comments, for the form, bootstrap has a form documentation here: [Bootstrap form documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). you should try something along the lines of this( give it your own dimension and criteria):

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="frmname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input name="frmname" style="width: 80%" type="text" class="text" required="required" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```